# Missing default hdri in shading option

Tags: materials, 3d-view, shaders

Am new to blender currently am learning from certain youtube tutorials. The problem is in all the youtube videos a shiny ball is seen the viewport of the shading option which is seen in most of the youtube tutorials, Mine is just all dark in loodevmode like that shiny ball is not showing up in the viewport, Whenever add an external hdri it is working But not getting that same result from the yt videos with default hdri. I don't know if the new 2.92 update removed it or not. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling blender but didn't work help me.[image][image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have enabled *Scene World* in the *Shading* options for the *Viewport*. In this case there is only an *HDRI Preview* when you actually use an HDRI in your world settings. If you disable *Scene World*, the Viewport shows a default HDRI. If this option is always there by default when opening a new scene, you have saved it to your startup file. To change it, when you're opening a new default scene, change the viewport option, then go to *File* > *Defaults* > *Save Startup File*.

[image: viewport shading]

Comment: No I checked it's always disabled whenever I open a default scean :(. Is there anything else that can go wrong pls help am always stuck cause of this problem.

Comment: Since it all looks quite black in your screenshot (by the way, would you mind taking a proper screenshot and add it to your question instead of this bad picture?), if _Scene World_ is disabled, what settings do you have for _Strength_ and _World Opacity_ in the shading options?

Comment: Done ✔. Can you check now :)

Comment: Hmmm... I can't get my world background to look so black, the only difference I can see now is that my _World Opacity_ by default is set to 0, but changing it to 1 like yours doesn't make it black... A black environment reflected in a mirror ball would of course make it black, too. Could you upload that file? [Click here and follow instructions to upload a blend file.](https://blend-exchange.com)

Comment: Done, bytheway thank you for taking your time to help me out .

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't reproduce this behaviour. On my PC at work and at home everything looks fine. What kind of graphics card do you have, maybe AMD? There are some questions here about problems with AMD drivers, they appear a little different but it might as well be what's happening with you. If that doesn't help, I would consider  installing the most recent Blender version to test it, maybe even experimental builds of 2.93.0 Beta or 3.0.0 Alpha.

Comment: For the AMD issues click these links: [Link 1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203869/object-is-not-showing-wires-in-wireframe-mode-and-turns-into-invisible-type-blac) , [Link 2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215120/blender-material-preview-and-rendered-view-arent-working-anymore) and [Link 3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra)

Comment: To be honest my pc don't even have a graphics card :* mine is a old pc with intel integrated graphics. I guess the problem  maybe with a lack of graphics card, anyways when I used to use blender 2.8 the default hdri used to show up and work properly maybe i will try downloading 2.8 or the version in development. I think there's no much help you can do for me here. If any i don't mind :). So thank you soo much for helping me out this was my first time using blender stack exchange i didn't except this quick response from someone. Thank you .